# Conditional Terms & Conditions based on Unique Combination of SKUs

Tags: cpq

I would like to add a "Statement of Works" to an order form generated from the quotes object in Salesforce based on a unique combination of products/SKUs selected. This is not a product bundle. There are specific combinations that would warrant it's own template or section to be added to the order form.

How can I do this?